# pyautogui.click() doesn't work on another program

Tags: python, pyautogui, on-screen-keyboard

Actually, I have written a code where I've an application such that I've to click the on-screen keyboard using this `pyautogui.click(button='left')`. But it is not working on on-screen keyboard. I'll be pleased to have your precious opinion. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Here's a similar question that may be of interest: [Application not responding to Windows API events?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44466855/945456). It may help to have some additional detail in your question. For example, you could edit the tags to show which operating system you're on, or [edit the question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/52857865/edit) to include a simplified code snippet to help us recreate the issue.

Comment: Oh! Thanks @JeffBridgman! Now, it works well.